# Get Get-MailboxStatistics, ItemCount as variable

Tags: powershell

i have simple question, how to get ItemCount as variable.
My code

```
$beforeDelete =  Get-MailboxStatistics test@test.com | ft ItemCount
```

im getting right now is

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Any know where is the problem?

Comment: `ft` = `Format-Table`. Use `...| Select -Expand ItemCount` instead

Comment: Thank you its working

Comment: Or dotted notation (Get-MailboxStatistics test@test.com).ItemCount